# Java JasperReport very slow

Tags: java, performance, jasper-reports

I am trying to create a JasperReport. But it takes around 10sec to execute "JasperFillManager.fillReport()". Does someone know why it takes so long?

```
public JasperViewer createReport(Long termin_id) {
    String reportSource = getClass().getResource("/reports/example.jrxml").getPath();
    parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.put("Terminnummer", termin_id);
    try {
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);
        Connection c = MySQL.getNativeConnection();
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, c); 
        jv = new JasperViewer(print, false);
        });
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return jv;
```

Thanks for your help.

Heres the jrxml file I'am using for this report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="repTermin" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
        <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
        <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
        <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
        <style name="Crosstab Data Text" hAlign="Center"/>
        <parameter name="Terminnummer" class="java.lang.Long"/>
        <parameter name="Bearbeiter" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="Teilnehmer" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <queryString>
                <![CDATA[SELECT t.*, a.AKTENZEICHENJAHR, a.AKTENZEICHENNUMMER, a.GRUND, a.BEZEICHNUNG, b.`NAME` AS ANLEGER, b2.`NAME` AS MITARBEITER
FROM demo.TERMIN t, demo.AKTE a, demo.BENUTZER b, demo.BENUTZER b2
WHERE t.ID = $P{Terminnummer} AND b.ID = t.ANLEGER_ID AND a.ID = t.AKTE_ID AND b2.ID = t.MITARBEITER_ID]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="ID" class="java.lang.Long"/>
        <field name="ART" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="BEMERKUNG" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="BESCHREIBUNG" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="DATUM" class="java.lang.Long"/>
        <field name="DAUER" class="java.lang.Long"/>
        <field name="ERSTELLT" class="java.lang.Long"/>
        <field name="NOTIZEN" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="ORT" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="PRIVAT" class="java.lang.Boolean"/>
        <field name="STATUS" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="AKTE_ID" class="java.lang.Long"/>
        <field name="ANLEGER_ID" class="java.lang.Long"/>
        <field name="MITARBEITER_ID" class="java.lang.Long"/>
        <field name="PERSON_ID" class="java.lang.Long"/>
        <field name="AKTENZEICHENJAHR" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="AKTENZEICHENNUMMER" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="GRUND" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="BEZEICHNUNG" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="ANLEGER" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="MITARBEITER" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <background>
                <band splitType="Stretch"/>
        </background>
        <title>
                <band height="146" splitType="Stretch">
                        <textField pattern="">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="100" width="555" height="20" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                                        <font fontName="Tahoma" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ART}.toString()+" am "+new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(new Date($F{DATUM}))+" ("+new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE").format(new Date($F{DATUM}))+") um "+new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date($F{DATUM}))+" Uhr"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                </band>
        </title>
        <pageHeader>
                <band height="6" splitType="Stretch">
                        <line>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="1"/>
                                <graphicElement>
                                        <pen lineWidth="3.0"/>
                                </graphicElement>
                        </line>
                </band>
        </pageHeader>
        <columnHeader>
                <band height="6" splitType="Stretch"/>
        </columnHeader>
        <detail>
                <band height="472" splitType="Stretch">
                        <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="219" height="18" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                                <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Tahoma" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Akten und Aktenzeichen]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="18" width="219" height="18" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                                <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Tahoma" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Bearbeiter der Akte]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="36" width="219" height="18" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                                <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Tahoma" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Termin bestimmt für]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="66" width="219" height="18" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                                <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Tahoma" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[weitere Teilnehmer]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="202" width="219" height="18" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                                <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Tahoma" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Bemerkung]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="231" width="219" height="18" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                                <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Tahoma" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Datum]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="249" width="219" height="18" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                                <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Tahoma" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Uhrzeit]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="267" width="219" height="18" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                                <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Tahoma" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Dauer]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="285" width="219" height="18" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                                <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Tahoma" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Ort des Termins]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="332" width="219" height="18" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                                <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Tahoma" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Termin notiert am]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="314" width="219" height="18" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                                <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Tahoma" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Termin notiert von]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <staticText>
                                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="363" width="219" height="18" backcolor="#CCCCCC"/>
                                <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Tahoma" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Notizen]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <textField>
                                <reportElement x="240" y="0" width="315" height="18"/>
                                <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Tahoma" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{AKTENZEICHENJAHR}+" - "+$F{AKTENZEICHENNUMMER}+" "+$F{GRUND}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="240" y="18" width="315" height="18"/>
                                <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Tahoma" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Bearbeiter}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                                <reportElement x="240" y="36" width="315" height="18"/>
                                <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Tahoma" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{MITARBEITER}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                                <reportElement x="240" y="202" width="315" height="18"/>
                                <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Tahoma" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{BEMERKUNG}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="240" y="231" width="315" height="18"/>
                                <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Tahoma" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd.MMMM yyyy").format(new Date($F{DATUM}))]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                                <reportElement x="240" y="249" width="315" height="18"/>
                                <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Tahoma" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date($F{DATUM}))]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                                <reportElement x="240" y="267" width="315" height="18"/>
                                <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Tahoma" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH").format(new Date($F{DAUER}))+"h "+new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("mm").format(new Date($F{DAUER}))+" min"]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                                <reportElement x="240" y="285" width="315" height="18"/>
                                <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Tahoma" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ORT}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                                <reportElement x="240" y="314" width="315" height="18"/>
                                <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Tahoma" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ANLEGER}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                                <reportElement x="240" y="332" width="315" height="18"/>
                                <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Tahoma" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd.MMMM yyyy, HH:mm").format(new Date($F{ERSTELLT}))]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                                <reportElement x="240" y="363" width="315" height="85"/>
                                <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Tahoma" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NOTIZEN}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                <reportElement x="240" y="66" width="315" height="114"/>
                                <textElement>
                                        <font fontName="Tahoma" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{Teilnehmer}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                </band>
        </detail>
        <columnFooter>
                <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
        </columnFooter>
        <pageFooter>
                <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
        </pageFooter>
        <summary>
                <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
        </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Does the "ignore pagination" option make any difference?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your report is using a sql query to get the data, have you tested to see how long just the SQL query takes to run?

The other issue is how much data are you returning in the query? The more there is, obviously the longer it is going to take.

Also you are recompiling the report on every run. While that may not be your hold up, you can use the cached version of the report.

Essentially:

- check if it is in the cache

  - if not compile it
- get compiled jasper file

You can compile it to a file by using `JasperCompileManager.compileReportToStream(inputStream, outputStream);` where output stream is a FileOutputStream;

Comment: The compiling is not the issue. Also the sql query, which returns 1 entry, takes less than a second. The problem seems to be in the fillReport() method.

Comment: @Andreas I assume you also eliminated the possibility it was taking a while to get your db connection? Do you have any other reports yet, and how long do they take? Other than that, you could post your jrxml, maybe there is something weird going on in there.

Comment: @AndreasLenggenhager were u able to resolve this issue. I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use virtualizer. Here I have listed sample sample code for it.

```
public InputStream xlsReportGen(String xml, String reportTemplate,
        String reportPath, Map<String, Object> reportParams)
        throws Exception {

    ByteArrayOutputStream _out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    JRDataSource datasource = new JRXmlDataSource(new File(xml));
    JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader
        .loadObjectFromFile(reportPath + reportTemplate);

    // creating the virtualizer
    JRSwapFile swapFile = new JRSwapFile(reportPath, 4096, 4096);
    JRAbstractLRUVirtualizer virtualizer = new JRSwapFileVirtualizer(5000,
        swapFile, true);
    reportParams.put(JRParameter.REPORT_VIRTUALIZER, virtualizer);

    JasperPrint _print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,
        reportParams, datasource);

    if (virtualizer != null) {
        virtualizer.cleanup();
    }

    JRXlsExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, _print);
    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, _out);
    exporter.setParameter(
        JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS,
        Boolean.TRUE);
    exporter.exportReport();

    return new ByteArrayInputStream(_out.toByteArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that your aren't using two datasource without need. It happended to me that jasper was using two datasources (main data sources and a subdataset) in a crosstab, but I needed only the main data source.